# for loop in file handling (python)

Tags: python, file-handling

```
f = open("food.txt", "r")

for line in f:
    print(line)
```

I don't understand how the above for loop reads the file line by line? Why not character by character or word by word?
please explain.

Comment: Because it has been decided that it would be so, because there is a lot of data that has to be read line by line. That's all.

Comment: do another for loop if you want the characters, ```for character in line```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Python works, `open` creates a `file-object`.

If you look at [I/O documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for file objects by default they read line by line!

In words from documentation: *"this is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code"*

In the previous versions of Python(2.2-), you had to specify byte limit for the same functionality!

For characters you can do:

```
for line in f: 
    for c in line: print(c)
```

For words you can do:

```
for line in f: 
    for w in line.split(): print(w)
```